# Deploying C# application that uses VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, deployment, vsto

I've recently built an application that pulls data from an Excel spreadsheet, which gets the data by running a macro. I put this already-existing Excel project into Visual Studio, and then wrote C# to do what I needed it to do. The issue I'm having is that when I deployed it to a network folder, there is no icon that runs the app. I ran the setup.exe and the .vsto, which both say were installed correctly, but can't find an icon that my users can press to run the app. I know I must be missing something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIy608De_40

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, I actually have watched the video and unfortunately, it doesn't quite apply to my situation as it is not a document level deployment. The users will never interact with Excel, so clicking on the .xlsm file won't start the app. It opens with a Windows form that takes some input that is then used to run the Excel macro. I would have thought the setup.exe would have done the trick, but no such luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is - I think you may be misunderstanding how VSTO works.If you have an Office project, the relevant Office application must be running for it to run. If it's an application-level project, you can start Excel any way you like (directly or by opening a file) and you typically would have custom controls somewhere that kick off your macro or do whatever you need to do.